# How many wings would a vertebrate-like hexapod have?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, flight

If there were six-limbed animals that were otherwise similar to vertebrates, I'm wonndering what's the most plausible way for them to evolve some of those limbs into wings would be. Would they be more likely to be bipeds with four wings or quadrupeds with two wings? Or perhaps they would be pterosaur/bat-like and walk on their wings.

I don't know a lot about locomotion (either terrestrial or airborne). I assume that generally flying evolves in small animals with an active lifestyle (possibly tree-dwelling, though the evidence in the fossil record is disputed), so I'm wondering which limbs of a such a hexapod would be most likely to become wings.

Comment: Why not all? With enough imagination all can work, you can make six limbed pterosaur walking on hid wings but he has 4 wings and two legs or 4 legs and 2 wings, more like a slender dragon.

Comment: Or you could make them like raptors which were starting to develop feathers for flight on their legs, you could even make an animal with 4 wings and 2 semi wings that act as legs.

Answer (score 3):

**Nobody knows**

Theoretically, either two or four pairs of wings are possible. On Earth, no animal has ever evolved where all of the limbs are solely devoted to flight and are incapable of terrestrial locomotion, for the simple reason that no animal can stay aloft forever. They have to land to lay eggs or give birth, if nothing else, and doing other things like sleeping, feeding, or mating on ground is useful.

Insects also aren't useful in this regard as their wings are not modified legs. A more apt description is that they are outgrowths of the skin that form wings (the actual origins of insect wings are debated, but its clear they aren't limbs in the way that bird, bat, or pterosaur wings are). So despite being hexapods all of their legs are still legs and aren't wings.

Given that only four groups of animals on Earth have ever developed wings (insects, pterosaurs, birds, and bats), we have no way of knowing for sure how having six limbs would promote or restrict the formation of different body plans.

Comment: But see for instance Changyuraptor yangi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changyuraptor or the way that some pterosaurs were quadrupedal, using the wings both for flight and for ground locomotion.

Comment: @user2352714 - Thanks! Birds, bats, and pterosaurs are all similar in that they use the front pair of limbs for flight, so I suppose(?) it's more plausible that either the front pair or the front two pairs of limbs would be wings in hexapods?

Comment: It's unclear that "no animal can stay aloft forever". That it hasn't happened isn't proof that it can't happen under any circumstances. Stephen Baxter even has fiction where a "sky whale" does just this in the Jurassic period... it's a giant pterosaur of some sort.

Comment: Also worth noting that staying aloft forever isn’t a requirement for having all limbs as wings. If you can also walk on the wings (pterosaur) or clamber with them (bat) there’s no reason to go full wing. I suspect most vertebrates don’t do that because it’s less efficient than just having two wings.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends honestly.**

There simply is no record of a hexapodal vertebrate to begin with. There's also a need to look at their environment, how dense is the atmosphere, how is gravity on the planet, etc. But by going out wild and trying to be a generalist and basing off on a science fiction I truly enjoyed, I'd say you'd be looking at either a [Mountain Banshee](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Mountain_Banshee) or a [Leonopteryx.](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Leonopteryx).

You see, one of the main adaptations for flight is to gain wings, the second is to become lighter. This is shown in how birds lost their teeth and longer tails after their wings, as a means to become lighter, along with adaptations like hollow or thinner bones. Why did I talk about this? Because extra legs usually mean extra weight, meaning it'll need extra lift to get out of the ground.

By basing upon the creatures of [Pandora](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Pandora) from the movie "James Cameron's avatar", we can get a good idea of how it could evolve, with the leonopteryx having 4 wings (2 primary ones and 2 secondary ones, which appear to be less developed, maybe in the process of being lost) and 2 muscular legs to grab prey; meanwhile the mountain Banshee seems to have lost 2 limbs altogether, relying either on its 4 arms or 2 arms and 2 legs (it's hard to tell whether the hind limbs are arms or legs, but I assume they might be legs due to having a good amount of structural differences to the arms) to fly, with the loss likely being to become lighter and fly faster (Note that in their planet flight is easier due to the denser atmosphere and weaker gravity).

So summing up, there's a good chance they might have a period with even all limbs being used as wings in some way, like the [microraptor](http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/species/m/microraptor.html), or they could have 4 wings and 2 legs. But I find it unlikely they'd have 4 "legs" and 2 wings mostly because 2 can usually do the job fine enough. So unless natural selection defined that 2 wings and 4 limbs for running/climbing were more advantageous, I could easily see them becoming 4 winged creatures, with legs for climbing/running like a bird or climbing like in birds and bats. However, if 2 wings were able to do the flying part just fine, there's a high chance the other 2 wings or even the legs(if the second pair could also do their job) would naturally be lost for the sake of becoming lighter.

Comment: If two wings is better for flight, I suppose it's also possible that a four-winged creature would become two-winged by making a single wing from two limbs. From the picture, it looks like the Leonopteryx might also be on that route. Like how butterflys technically have four wings but they don't move them independently.

Comment: @Dark Malthorp that's not impossible, but I don't think it's likely. Maybe the anchoring points for the second wing's muscles could become attachment points for extra muscles from the main pair, but I simply think it's easier for the main wings to become stronger while the second ones disappear than for both pairs to fuse into a single one. But again, there's no evidence that it couldn't happen.